# From my work, men gain light

Tags: riddle

From my work, men gain light
Yet my work keeps me out of sight
Moving matter to different places
Concealing the most jagged faces
Construction without a hard hat
Where most have curvy, I have flat

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> The Wind?

From my work, men gain light

> Wind electricity generator

Yet my work keeps me out of sight

> You can't really see the wind.

Moving matter to different places

> The wind moves clouds and dust around, even sand, etc.

Concealing the most jagged faces

> Given time, even most jagged surfaces will get smoothed by the wind

Construction without a hard hat

> The wind doesn't really wear a hat

Where most have curvy, I have flat

> Not sure on this, seems to me similar to the previous about the jagged surface.

Comment: I gather there is an up-vote for the effort but I didn't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> A microchip?

From my work, men gain light

> Something to do with computer monitors?

Yet my work keeps me out of sight

> Not on display when working.

Moving matter to different places

> Robots!

Concealing the most jagged faces

> ...

Construction without a hard hat

> Roboooots! :D

Where most have curvy, I have flat

> Brains!  A computer brain is flat while bio-brains are curvy!  This is probably my strongest connection and actually... I probably haven't got this one...

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Shadow?

From my work, men gain light

> By existing, shadow provides the constrast that we need to notice light - can anything be "light" without darkness?

Yet my work keeps me out of sight

> Things in shadow are often hard to see.

Moving matter to different places

> Not entirely sure here, maybe to do with dark matter?

Concealing the most jagged faces

> When features become difficult to distinguish in shadow

Construction without a hard hat

> Not sure... maybe because it's a "shady" practice :P

Where most have curvy, I have flat

> Shadows of 3D objects are projected onto a 2D plane (shadows are flat)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> Undersea Cable?

From my work, men gain light

> Transferring electricity to power the light

Yet my work keeps me out of sight

> "Hidden" as in under water/sea

Moving matter to different places

> Transferring electricity

Concealing the most jagged faces

> Not too sure, but jagged wires hidden from the cover

Construction without a hard hat

> Undersea construction does not need a hard hat

Where most have curvy, I have flat

> Most cable line are curvy, yet this one is flat

Answer (score 1):

My answer

> Beaver

From my work, men gain light

> beaver's work inspired the dam, like the Hoover Dam, which gives electricity or light.

Yet my work keeps me out of sight

> the beaver's dam is built to hide it and it's family

Moving matter to different places

> beavers move trees and plants to make the dam

Concealing the most jagged faces

> then the beaver is hidden, along with their toothy faces

Construction without a hard hat

> beavers chop trees without a hat

Where most have curvy, I have flat

> Beavers have a flat tail where most tails are curvy.  This is the refining point of the riddle.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> God?

From my work, men gain light

> From Genesis 1 of the Bible: "Then God commanded, “Let there be light”—and light appeared."

Yet my work keeps me out of sight

> This God has never been seen, as best we can deduce.

Moving matter to different places

> God, being all-powerful, can move land, create continents and oceans, etc. according to the Bible.

Concealing the most jagged faces

> Genisis 1 goes that God created oceans, which would have obscured many an underwater rocky mountain.

Construction without a hard hat

> Would you picture God doing all this while wearing a hard hat?

Where most have curvy, I have flat

> Humans are all 3-dimensional (and thus 'curvy') but God could theoretically be 2-dimensional?

Answer (score -2):

Is it

> a coal or a diamond miner?

Comment: Do you mind explaining how you got your answer?

Comment: @MikeEarnest - thanks for the edit, I was on mobile